# How to pass event from component to nested function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got two splitted functions and I need to pass a value from one to the other, which I'm doing like shown below. What is the difference between `const handleClick = icon.onClick(category)` and `const handleClick = () => icon.onClick(category)`?

And how do I pass the `event` from the component to the `handleClick()` function?

```
export const useCategories = () => {
  const handleClick = (category, something) => {
    event.stopPropagation() // <-- 3. How to get event?
    console.log(category, something) // <-- 4. Get every value
  }

  return {
    icon: {
      onClick: (category) => handleClick(category, 'anything') // <-- 2. add second var value
    }
  }
}

export const Categories = () => {
  const { icon } = useCategories()

  return (
      <div>
        {categories.map((category) => {
          const handleClick = icon.onClick(category) // <-- 1. pass category value
          return <Icon onClick={handleClick} />)}
        }
      </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: `<Icon onClick={(event)=>handleClick(event,catergory)} />)` are you looking for this?

Comment: your first example assigns the result of a function call to `handleClick`, your second example assigns a function that you can then call later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to proxy the event object through on all click handlers. I like to use curried functions to make attaching the click handler a little simpler. Don't forget to add a react key to the mapped icons.

```
export const useCategories = () => {
  const handleClick = (event, category, something) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log(category, something);
  };

  return {
    icon: {
      // curried function to receive category and return onClick handler
      onClick: category => event => handleClick(event, category, 'anything'),
    }
  }
}

export const Categories = () => {
  const { icon } = useCategories();

  return (
    <div>
      {categories.map((category, index) => (
        <Icon
          key={index}
          onClick={icon.onClick(category)} // <-- set category
        />
      )
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: And if the component onClick would pass two values, the curried function would look like `(category, group) => event => handleClick(event, category, group, 'anything')`, right? And event is always the first parameter...

Comment: @user3142695 Yes, that is correct for the currying part... as for the argument order when passing along the event object, that is flexible. You can define the arguments in just about any order you like, so long as you are consistent in usage. I believe it is *a* convention to send the event object as the first argument.

Comment: And last question: Why don't I have to use `() => icon.onClick(category)` instead of just `icon.onClick(category)` in the icon component as I am passing a parameter?

Comment: @user3142695 When writing curried functions, notice you are creating a function that *returns* a function. It is this returned function that is used as the callback for the click event. If you wanted to write it as an anonymous function like that then you would need to also invoke the returned function, i.e. something like this `(event) => icon.onClick(category)(event)`. I hope that clarifies how a curried function is used.

Answer (score 2):

The **onevent** handlers are properties on certain DOM elements to manage how that element reacts to events.
When the event handler is specified as an HTML attribute, the specified code is wrapped into a function with the following parameters:

- **event** — for all event handlers except **onerror**.
- **event**, **source**, **lineno**,**colno**, and **error** for the **onerror** event handler.
  Note that the event      parameter actually contains the error
  message as a string.

When the event handler is invoked, the this keyword inside the handler is set to the DOM element on which the handler is registered. For more details, see, see [the this keyword documentation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#In_an_inline_event_handler)

if you want more see, [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers#when_the_event_handler_is_invoked)

but in your code, you need to add this

```
 <Icon onClick={(event) => icon.onClick(event, category, ...rest)} />
```

Answer (score 1):

As you want to pass the `event` and `category` to the click handler, modify the function passed to `onClick` to pass the args.

```
export const useCategories = () => {
  const handleClick = (event, ...rest) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log(rest);
  };

  return {
    icon: {
      onClick: (event, category) => handleClick(event, category, 'anything'),
    },
  };
};

export const Categories = () => {
  const { icon } = useCategories();

  return (
    <div>
      {categories.map((category) => {
        return <Icon onClick={(event) => icon.onClick(event, category)} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

1. When you dont need to pass parametrs you use

   `onClick={func}`

   When you want to pass parametrs you use

   `onClick={() => func(someParmeter)}`
2. To pass the event simply write

   `onClick={e => func(e)}`

Comment: `onClick={func}` and `onClick={e => func(e)}` are identical. The event is always implicitly passed in as the first argument to the `onClick` event handler